Genomics vendors with publicly available pricing
Are there vendors for genomics with publicly available pricing?
Motivation:

I'm curious why the reagents needed for gene cloning using bacterial plasmid costs 100-150 USD, and why this can't be made cheaper. If the reagents can be purchased in bulk for  cheap and the research labour can be automated, so that a gene cloning costs 1 USD instead of 100 USD, then the entire field of research will be able to iterate very quickly.
If I google each of these steps I can find the required amount of each reagent, but the prices of the reagents are not available. For example for DNA ligation, how much does T4 DNA ligase cost?


What do you want to clone? And most important: Why? What do you hope from this?

@Chris I want to clone using bacterial plasmid, on species for example ecoli, I've added it to the post. I could provide lot more specifics like which species and which plasmid etc if it'll affect the cost a lot

@Chris Goal is I'm wondering if there's a way to really cheaply and quickly test if a certain genetic modification produces a certain protein or not. Being able to run this type of test millions of times seems like it'll move the field forward quickly.

There are ways to test this: You can do mutation screens on expressed proteins, but first you need to clone this. And as far as I know, this has to be done by hand. The process is relatively easy, but I don't see you can automate everything. You will in most cases get a protein, if this expresses in E.coli or is functional, is another thing.

@Chris Yes I understand automation is a difficult problem. Might need microfluidic system, and might need AI. (I'd love to read more on how one will actually try to automate it, but it's a separate question) For automation to even be worth attempting though, cost of reagents has to be much lower than $100. Hence wondering what the actual cost of reagents in bulk is, for gene cloning.

Ok, turn out, I was wrong: There are already automated services that you can buy: https://www.nzytech.com/en/hs0070-high-throughput-gene-synthesis/ Still leaves you with the problem of testing these proteins and optimize conditions for overexpression. Both are no simple tasks.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about biology.

This is not a question of biology - it is a question for market economics. Reagents cost because that's what the market has set them at. Note that it isn't like you can just pull T4 ligase of the shelf or make it from scratch by just chcking amino acids into a tube, it is a whole manufacturing set up with fermenters expressing the right plasmids under the right conditions, batch processing, multiple purification steps, quality control, validation, testing etc. All require a LOT of equipment, reagents, time, people and it simply costs money to do so.

And - yes, simply go to company websites, they do tell you how much it costs to get a certain amount. e.g. ThermoFisher T4, 1000U, 5U/ul, 5000 U, 30 U/ul,  or NEB's selection among many.

I think that https://www.inscripta.com/ has a business model something like this, not that it seems to be going particularly well. (I got laid off after working there, I have no financial stake.) It is also similar to Ginkgo, they are also not doing particularly well.

@bob1 I figured out the problem, I had to to set VPN location to USA to view prices. Thanks!

@MaximilianPress Thanks for this. I couldn't find any information about inscripta's research though.

They haven't done a good job of publishing. This article talks about several applications they worked on at one point. But like I said they're not doing very well business wise- they had issues with low demand for their product. So I'm not sure that you'll find much. Look at Ginkgo or Willow though, or Amyris. They have similar goals.

@MaximilianPress Thanks, I will check!

Set your VPN location to USA then visit ThermoFisher 1 2 or NEB 3 website.
Credits to @bob1 for making me realise the websites view differently depending on country.

Prices often vary by location, so viewing prices with a VPN may not show you the price you will actually pay in your location.

@BryanKrause Fair point! P.S. Do you know why I'm being downvoted?
